# Goal Seek based off cells with formulas

Tags: vba, excel-formula, return-value

I'm trying to use goal seek across multiple sheets to updated the projects return on sale %. All of the cells have formulas and there is one cell that we hard code in order to tie back to our original return on sale %.

Below is the code I'm using, pretty straight forward.

for some reason when I run this macro its not giving me the desired value I would like for the return on sale %

```
Sheets("DEV INFAS WLKDN").Select
    Range("F30").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("F30").GoalSeek Goal:=-0.002, ChangingCell:=Range("F19")

Sheets("NBN WLKDN").Select
    Range("F30").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("F30").GoalSeek Goal:=-0.0062, ChangingCell:=Range("F19")

Sheets("MSIL LASER WLKDN").Select
    Range("F30").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("F30").GoalSeek Goal:=-0.004, ChangingCell:=Range("F19")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what value you're expecting and what its giving you, its hard to say why you might be getting an unexpected answer.  The goal seek function in Excel is basically an iterative guessing function and is not guaranteed to return a globally optimal value.  I don't have any documentation to support this claim but I'm pretty sure the goal seek function in Excel implements either a [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) or [golden-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search) search.  To the best of my knowledge Excel doesn't specify what they are using under the hood, but these would be reasonable searches to use and looking into how they work might shed light on your issue.

Also, it looks like the length of your code could be reduced to

```
With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets("DEV INFAS WLKDN").Range("F30").GoalSeek Goal:=-0.002, ChangingCell:=Range("F19")
    .Sheets("NBN WLKDN").Range("F30").GoalSeek Goal:=-0.0062, ChangingCell:=Range("F19")
    .Sheets("MSIL LASER WLKDN").Range("F30").GoalSeek Goal:=-0.004, ChangingCell:=Range("F19")
End With
```

generally `.Select` is unnecessary and not recommended.

Comment: thank you are you able to recommend another formula that could help me with my issue?

Comment: @jonathanmarin I cannot recommend anything without knowing what other formulas are used in the goal seek